AG-Grid with AngularJS v1.4.7
UI is working fine.  What I am having a problem with is the onCellClicked event.  You have to click it 2 times for the AngularJS model ng-form to update.  So, it is like AG-Grid is somehow stopping the AngularJS code from running fully the 1st time.  And this happens for every row/click.  You have to close the model windows and click the edit button again to get the correct ng-form.
I am including AG-Grid using the following link: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
Thanks.
Using a setTimeout function didn't help.
